Three different tags involving "morphology", but do they truly differ?
We have:

mathematical-morphology (181 questions)
image-morphology (293 questions)
morphological-analysis (84 questions)

Their descriptions don't help me pick one over the other. All three seem to represent the same concept, within acceptable tolerance. I certainly can't tell how the sets of watchers would differ.
Please discuss. Should these tags be synonymized? If anyone wants to try explaining how they differ, or why they should differ, I'm all ears.

Thanks VLAZ for pointing out two things I should not have missed: the first two tags are synonyms already, and the third tag is something entirely different (NLP thing) that's being misapplied a lot. I'm going through those questions and fixing the tags now.

The tag image-morphology is currently a synonym of mathematical-morphology. So they are already the same.
However, I do not see how morphological analysis relates at all to those. Other than the name, it has nothing in common.

mathematical-morphology / image-morphology is an image processing technique tapping into geometry.
morphological-analysis is an approach to solving complex multi-factor problems.


thanks for pointing this out. I failed to notice those things and don't know how. must be the late hour. some of the questions under [tag:mathematical-morphology] probably need retagging.
